# Putting a Java/Slick game on your website?

Tags: java, slick

I've made a simple little 2D game in Java using Slick and I want to embed it in my website. I'm just a little confused as to how to go about it, I'm guessing I need to export it as a WAR file?

Sorry if this isn't really specific but oddly enough I couldn't find *any* information on this subject. I think I may lack the basic vernacular to describe my question, because most of my Google and other searches turn up completely unrelated results any help would be appreciated, I just need a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "[Java applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet)".

So I just did a fast Google search for "java slick applet" and found this:
http://ninjacave.com/slickapplet

Comment: Thanks, I think this is it. Sometimes you just need that refresher, thanks!